# Datepicker range don't allow the check out date to same day

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm trying to do check-in and check-out date for the same day but it not let me do that. Please help me to do this.

```
var ajax_check_var = '';
$('.location_search_results_ul').hide();

$("#check_in_time").datepicker({
    showOtherMonths: true,
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
    minDate: 0,
    //for calender Css
    beforeShowDay: function (date) {
        return highlightDateBorder($("#check_in_time").val(), date);
    },
    onSelect: function(selectedDate) {
        var date_format = selectedDate.split("-");
        var selectedDate = new Date($.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', new Date(date_format[2], date_format[1] - 1, date_format[0])));
        selectedDate.setDate(selectedDate.getDate() + 1);
        $("#check_out_time").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
    },
});

$("#check_out_time").datepicker({
    showOtherMonths: true,
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
    //for calender Css
    beforeShowDay: function (date) {
        return highlightDateBorder($("#check_out_time").val(), date);
    },
    beforeShow: function (input, instance) {
        var date_to = $('#check_in_time').val();
        if (typeof date_to != 'undefined' && date_to != '') {
            var date_format = date_to.split("-");
            var selectedDate = new Date($.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', new Date(date_format[2], date_format[1] - 1, date_format[0])));
            selectedDate.setDate(selectedDate.getDate()+1);
            $("#check_out_time").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
        } else {
            var date_format = new Date();
            var selectedDate = new Date($.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', new Date()));
            selectedDate.setDate(selectedDate.getDate()+1);
            $("#check_out_time").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On multiple occasions in your code you set the `minDate` of the `check_out_time` datepicker to `selectedDate`. However `selectedDate` is never the actual selected date but the selected date + 1 because of the following line.

```
selectedDate.setDate(selectedDate.getDate()+1)
```

Altering that should allow you to select the same day.

I also suggest cleaning up all the repeating code, you have a lot of behavior that is repeated a few times and it makes it a mess to read :)
You can move three lines to a function and call that instead of just repeating basically the same logic in three places.

```
const date_format = selectedDate.split("-");
setMinData(new Date(date_format[2], date_format[1] - 1, date_format[0]));

function setMinDate(date) {
    var selectedDate = new Date($.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date));
    selectedDate.setDate(selectedDate.getDate() + 1);
    $("#check_out_time").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
}
```

Comment: Can you please edit my code over there? I'm unable to understand which all lines I have used many times.

Comment: I'm not editing all of your code for you, sorry. I gave you quite a lot of pointers and even made the function with call for you.

Comment: No issue, if you can't do it. I can understand that.

Comment: It's not really the point of this site to have people clean up your code for you. I don't think you will find many people on the internet that will do that for free.

Comment: No issue bro, I just asked you to help. If you can't there's nothing wrong. Point of this site is to help. I'm not asking you to configure or change my whole site of codes. I'm just confused here and couldn't get myself off from here.

Comment: The 3 lines inside my method are used multiple times (at `onSelect` of the `check_in_time` and 2 times in the `beforeShow` of `check_out_time`).

Comment: Removing +1 from this (selectedDate.setDate(selectedDate.getDate()+1) sollved the selecting dates but it not let me search. If it's do it's taking the next day automatically.

Comment: I don't understand what other issue you're having since it's not reflected in your original question. Besides, I solved your original issue so my answer is the accepted one. Another issue would require another question.